# Show if / Hide if in dictionary choices?

Tags: docassemble

I have been building a questions using the method shown at the bottom of the entry on Multiple Choice Lists, here: https://docassemble.org/docs/fields.html#field%20with%20choices (i.e. by specifying a list of dictionaries in a `code` block following a `choices` declaration.

It seems many properties can be held in the dictionary - I'm wondering if there's a way to use `hide if` / `show if` in the same way (i.e. by adding a key-value pair to the relevant dictionary(ies)? If so, I haven't been able to crack it. I think it should be possible, because as far as I can tell each choice for any multiple choice question is a python dictionary, but I'd love to know if it's possible, how?

I.E. expanding on the example in the docs:

```
question: |
  What type of shoes do you wear?
field: target_variable
choices:
  code: |
    [{'sneakers': "Sneakers",
      'help': "Comfortable shoes.",
      'css class': "sneakers",
      'color': "secondary"},
     {'sandals': "Sandals",
      'help': "For summer.",
      'css class': "sandals",
      'color': "danger",
      'hide_if':"shopping_for_arctic_attire'}, # something like this?
     {'clogs': "Clogs",
      'help': "For hippies.",
      'css class': "clogs",
      'color': "warning",
      'show_if': "needs_arch_support"}, # something like this?
     {'other': "Other",
      'default': True,
      'help': "Because the other types suck.",
      'css class': "othershoe",
      'color': "success"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has been added in version 1.4.42 of docassemble. The syntax for your example would be:

```
     {'sandals': "Sandals",
      'help': "For summer.",
      'css class': "sandals",
      'color': "danger",
      'show if': not shopping_for_arctic_attire},
```

Answer (score 1):

`choice` options can't use `show if` or `hide if`. You can do this another way by defining the options in code elsewhere.

```yaml
---
mandatory: True
code: |
  get_shoe_options
  target_variable
---
code: |
  shoe_options = [{'sneakers': "Sneakers",
      'help': "Comfortable shoes.",
      'css class': "sneakers",
      'color': "secondary"},
     {'other': "Other",
      'default': True,
      'help': "Because the other types suck.",
      'css class': "othershoe",
      'color': "success"}]
  
  if not shopping_for_arctic_attire:
    shoe_options.append({'sandals': "Sandals",
      'help': "For summer.",
      'css class': "sandals",
      'color': "danger"
    })
  
  if needs_arch_support:
    shoe_options.append({'clogs': "Clogs",
      'help': "For hippies.",
      'css class': "clogs",
      'color': "warning"
    })
  
  get_shoe_options = True
---
question: |
  What type of shoes do you wear?
field: target_variable
choices:
  code: |
    shoe_options
```